# How should I pass an int into stringWithFormat?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am try to use stringWithFormat to set a numerical value on the text property of a label but the following code is not working. I cannot cast the int to NSString. I was expecting that the method would know how to automatically convert an int to NSString.

What do I need to do here?

```
- (IBAction) increment: (id) sender
{
    int count = 1;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", count];
}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Do this:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
```

Comment: This produces a warning when compiling for 64-bit devices where `int` is actually a `long`.

Answer (score 49):

Keep in mind that @"%d" will only work on 32 bit. Once you start using NSInteger for compatibility if you ever compile for a 64 bit platform, you should use @"%ld" as your format specifier.

Comment: Using `%ld` when compiling for a 32-bit device now produces a warning. Which way is safer? Using `%ld` with 32 bits or using `%d` with 64?

Comment: Nevermind I see squelart's note about casting to `long` first. That does the trick and now compiles for either target without a warning!

Answer (score 42):

Marc Charbonneau wrote:

> Keep in mind that @"%d" will only work on 32 bit. Once you start using NSInteger for compatibility if you ever compile for a 64 bit platform, you should use @"%ld" as your format specifier.

Interesting, thanks for the tip, I was using @"%d" with my `NSInteger`s!

The SDK documentation also recommends to cast `NSInteger` to `long` in this case (to match the @"%ld"), e.g.:

```
NSInteger i = 42;
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)i];
```

Source: [String Programming Guide for Cocoa - String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) (Requires iPhone developer registration)

Answer (score 24):

You want to use `%d` or `%i` for integers. `%@` is used for objects.

It's worth noting, though, that the following code will accomplish the same task and is much clearer.

```
label.intValue = count;
```

Answer (score 13):

And for comedic value:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:count]];
```

(Though it could be useful if one day you're dealing with NSNumber's)

Comment: Or use the modern objective-c syntax and use: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(count)]

Answer (score 6):

To be 32-bit and 64-bit safe, use one of the [Boxed Expressions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions):

```
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(count).stringValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the snippet you posted just a sample to show what you are trying to do?

The reason I ask is that you've named a method `increment`, but you seem to be using that to set the value of a text label, rather than incrementing a value.

If you are trying to do something more complicated - such as setting an integer value and having the label display this value, you could consider using bindings. e.g

You declare a property `count` and your `increment` action sets this value to whatever, and then in IB, you bind the label's text to the value of `count`. As long as you follow Key Value Coding (KVC) with `count`, you don't have to write any code to update the label's display. And from a design perspective you've got looser coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget for `long long int`:

```
long long int id = [obj.id longLongValue];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is my id: %lld", id]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * formattedname;
NSString * firstname;
NSString * middlename;
NSString * lastname;

firstname = @"My First Name";
middlename = @"My Middle Name";
lastname = @"My Last Name";

formattedname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Full Name: %@ %@ %@", firstname, middlename, lastname];
NSLog(@"\n\nHere is the Formatted Name:\n%@\n\n", formattedname);

/*
Result:
Here is the Formatted Name:
My Full Name: My First Name My Middle Name My Last Name
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", XYZ]; 

//result:   label.text = XYZ
//use %d for int values
```