# NSString with NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, int, nsinteger

How can I put my NSInteger into my NSString stringWithFormat:

my code:

```
-(IBAction)main:(id)sender
{
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"return the clipboard"];


NSAppleEventDescriptor *clipboardTXT = [[script executeAndReturnError:nil]stringValue];

NSInteger *length = [clipboardTXT.stringValue length];

NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%", length];


[mybutton setTitle:mystring];
}
```

p.s. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404201/casting-nsinteger-into-nsstring?rq=1) but it didn't work for me.

[output](http://cl.ly/KWNP)

Comment: Seing the many errors in this code and your other questions, I strongly suggest to start with a good book about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%d` specifier.

```
- (IBAction)main:(id)sender
{
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"return the clipboard"];


    NSAppleEventDescriptor *clipboardTXT = [script executeAndReturnError:nil];

    NSInteger length = [[clipboardTXT stringValue] length];

    NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", length];

    [mybutton setTitle:mystring];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your problem is a totally different one then what you're asking. Why didn't you include the error message the first time? Time waster...

It obviously points out that the problem has to be somewhere around your `stringValue` calls. If you had googled it you certainly would've found that this error message means the object you're sending `stringValue` to, doesn't have such a method. `executeAndReturnError` returns an `NSAppleEventDescriptor` instance. You then call `stringValue` which will return an `NSString`, not an `NSAppleEventDescriptor`. After that you're sending a `stringValue` message to an `NSString` (it doesn't have such a method). See my edited code.

Comment: It should. What does it do instead of what you expect?

Comment: You're using a pointer when you shouldn't. The `length` method returns a primitive NSInteger (not an object). See my answer.

Comment: @AlexWayne I added my output.

Comment: @s0ulp1xel Actually, none of that code makes sense. The types are wrong, the methods are wrong (hence the problem in your output), pointers where they shouldn't be, wrong/missing format specifiers...

Comment: You're also randomly mixing up dot syntax and bracket syntax. `stringValue` and `length` are both methods, not properties.

Comment: @DrummerB I did google it but I guess I didn't find what your answer is stating. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

2 things, you want to use the `%d` specifier and you need to remove the `*` in your length declaration

```
NSInteger length = [clipboardTXT.stringValue length];
NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", length];
```