# iOS: Create String from Variable and string combined

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to concatenate a string and a variable together - I kind of find lots of examples of adding a string prior to a variable but not the other way round - how do I do this?

```
 NSString *theImage = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@" resimagefiletitle"] description], @"'add on the end";
```

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384089/how-should-i-pass-an-int-into-stringwithformat

Comment: cheers @ungot Basa - basically I need this in reverse ie a concatenation of Variable then string - not string then variable - is that poss?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Just use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ string I want added on end", variableName]. This assumes that variableName returns an NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
NSString *theImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[self.detailItem valueForKey:@" resimagefiletitle"], @"'add on the end"];
```

Or:

```
NSString *theImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ add on the end",[self.detailItem valueForKey:@" resimagefiletitle"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

NSString *theImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ '>",[[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"resimagefiletitle"] description]];

Here I am considering `[[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"resimagefiletitle"] description]` gives NSString

Answer (score 0):

We can concat diffrent type of datatypes into string by mention the format for it.

like if your want to concat two or more strings together then you can use the following code:

NSString *NewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"This Is",@"way to concate string"];

and if your want concat integer value then you can mention the data format for it "%i".
eg:
int OutOf = 150;
NSString *NewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",@"I got 100 out of ",OutOf];

this may help you.