# update query syntax in ios7 using sql server2008

Tags: ios, sql-server

```
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update MobileAppFeedback SET Feedback='%@' WHERE CustomerId='%@' ",self.UIFeedbackTextView.text,MobileAppUserIDlocal];
```

This query syntax is not working but when we are trying to update the values by hardcoding it inside the query it works, but it doesn't retrieve from other fields like `textField` from iOS .....please let me know the correct syntax

Comment: this query syntax is not working but when we are trying to update the values by hardcoding it inside the query it works .....nut it doest not retrieve from other fields like textField from iOS  .....please let me know the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct format specifier, you should use %ld for integers:

```
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update MobileAppFeedback SET Feedback='%@' WHERE CustomerId='%ld' ",self.UIFeedbackTextView.text,(long)MobileAppUserIDlocal];
```

See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/384219/563802